# I have multiple rows in a select command which are filled with events. now I want to calculate the time between the events:

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Trip.tripId
    ,Trip.vehicleid
    ,Trip.deviceid
    ,Trip.location
    ,Trip.event
    ,Trip.officeid
    ,Trip.eventdate
    ,IIf([PreviousDate] IS NULL, 0, + CAST(DateDiff(minute, [PreviousDate], [eventdate]) % 60 AS VARCHAR(100)) + 'min' + CAST(DateDiff(second, [PreviousDate], [eventdate]) % 60 AS VARCHAR(100)) + 'sec') AS [Deviation Time]
FROM (
    SELECT tripId
        ,vehicleid
        ,deviceid
        ,location
        ,officeid
        ,event
        ,eventdate
        ,(
            SELECT Max(eventdate)
            FROM Trip AS T2
            WHERE
                --T2.location=T1.location and
                --T2.event=T1.event and
                --  and
                T2.eventdate < T1.eventdate
                AND T2.tripId = T1.tripId
            ) AS PreviousDate
    FROM Trip AS T1
    ) AS Trip
WHERE officeid = 355
    AND vehicleid = 8306
    AND event LIKE '%deviation%'
ORDER BY tripId
    ,eventdate
```

Comment: SELECT Trip.tripId, Trip.vehicleid, Trip.deviceid, Trip.location, Trip.event, Trip.officeid, Trip.eventdate, IIf([PreviousDate] Is Null, 0,+ CAST( DateDiff(minute,[PreviousDate],[eventdate])%60 as varchar(100)) +'min'+ CAST( DateDiff(second,[PreviousDate],[eventdate])%60 as varchar(100))+'sec') as [Deviation Time] FROM ( SELECT tripId, vehicleid, deviceid, location, officeid, event, eventdate, ( SELECT Max(eventdate) FROM Trip AS T2 WHERE --T2.location=T1.location and --T2.event=T1.event and -- and T2.eventdate < T1.eventdate and T2.tripId = T1.tripId

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @Neeraj:please look here on how to ask :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

By far the simplest method is to use the ANSI standard function `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(minute,
                lag(eventdate) over (partition by eventid order by eventdate),
                eventdate
               ) as timediff_minutes
from trip t;
```

I don't fully understand how you want to format the difference, but the simplest way to get the values is using window functions.